# How to change a table (create/alter) so that the calculated “Average score” field is shown when querying the entire table without using INSERT, UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Marks. I want to add a column Average_score which will be calculated like `(Math+Physics)/2` How can I do that without update and insert?

```
Select *, (Math+Physics)/2 from Marks
```

Isn't the right answer, I need to modify the structure.

[image: Table Marks]

Comment: Typically you would not store such a value in the table. You would just calculate it whenever you need it.

Comment: Hi there, if you need a calculated field and don't want to update or insert data on it it makes no sense to alter the table structure (unless your update insert has another meaning). Now IF you asking that that field to be calculated automatically and added into your modified structure you will need a Trigger to do so. So please clarify it a little bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new generated column to your table like this:

```
alter table Marks add column `Average Score` float 
generated always as ((Math + Physics) / 2) virtual;
```

You can change the column to be `stored` and not `virtual`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hA2hggV8vxM15Z8SJbpxAC/3).
Results:

```
| N   | Surname | Name | Math | Physics | Average Score   |
| --- | ------- | ---- | ---- | ------- | --------------- |
| 1   | Smith   | Ann  | 5    | 4       | 4.5             |
| 2   | Perkins | Zoe  | 2    | 3       | 2.5             |
| 3   | Jones   | Rick | 5    | 5       | 5               |
```

More about generated columns here: 
[CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) and [ALTER TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html)

Comment: Learned something new today. didn't know about `generated always` feature! Thanks!

Comment: You are the best! Thank you!